# How to create DialogHost on one Grid and call on another Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm looking for a way to make my `DialogHost` centered in the middle of the WPF application, for that I need to create it in `MainGrid`.

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True">
       <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
           <Grid Margin="20">
               <TextBlock Text="My first Dialog" />
           </Grid>
       </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
   </materialDesign:DialogHost>
   
    <Grid Name="Grid1" Width="250" Height ="Auto">
        ... //MyCode
        <Button Name="MyButton" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}" Click="ButtonClick">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However, the button that I will use to call this `DialogHost` is in `Grid1`.

Is it possible to do that ? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs#open-dialog-strategies) routed command provided by Material Design. If you assign it as `Command` to your button, it will raise a routed event that bubbles up the visual tree until it reaches a `DialogHost` that handles it by showing the the dialog. For example:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
```

Since this meachanism works by searching a **parent** dialog host, you have to assign your [views as content](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs) of it. This means moving your `Grid` inside the `DialogHost` tags after the `DialogContent`.

For your case, you would put the `DialogHost` directly into the window or your `MainGrid` and put your `Grid1` into the dialog host content. Finally, you just have to assign the `OpenDialogCommand` to the button.

```
<Window ...>
   <Grid Name="MainGrid">
      <materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True">
         <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <Grid Margin="20">
               <TextBlock Text="My first Dialog" />
            </Grid>
         </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
         <Grid Name="Grid1" Width="250" Height ="Auto">
            <Button Name="MyButton"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
                    Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">
         </Grid>
      </materialDesign:DialogHost>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Grid1 is a column where I have several buttons, images, texts, fields, checkbox,...
would there be a problem with these Grid1 codes being inside `materialDesign:DialogHost`?

Comment: @Michael No, the dialog host just acts as a container, there should not be any problem. It is designed this way so that you can execute the open command from within the content, which will raise a routed event that can only be handled if the `DialogHost` is a parent of the corresponding button.